# Check if list is empty

Tags: python, list

I have this block of code:

```
while(active == True):

    print("\n*** Movie Title Explorer ***\n \tl - load file of movie titles\n \tr - random movie\n \ts - search\n \t"
          + "sw - starts with\n \tk - keep - save the last displayed movie title to your favourites\n \t"
          + "f - favourites display\n \tc - clear favourites\n \tq - quit") 

    command = input("Enter a command: ")


    if(command == "l"):
        movieList = loadMovie()

    elif(command == "r"):

        randomMovie(movieList)

    elif(command == "s"):
        searchMovies(movieList)

    elif(command == "sw"):
        startsWithSearch(movieList)
```

Each of these functions work correctly. What I want to do is check if movieList is empty in each of the elif blocks. This means that a user cannot perform operations (such as random and search) unless a file has been loaded into movieList.
I have tried using:

```
if movieList == []:
    print("Load file first")
```

And:

```
assert(movieList == []), "Load file first"
```

However, I keep getting this error: local variable 'movieList' referenced before assignment.
How do I check if movieList is empty to prevent a user from performing operations if no file is loaded?

Comment: `if not movieList:` is one way of doing it. But it seems you haven't assigned to `movieList` yet.

Comment: googling the error message would've gotten you the answer instantly.  no reason to post a question here for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put

```
movieList=[]
```

above that check

```
if movieList == []:
    print("Load file first")
```

because it sounds like you're assuming movieList is getting assignment before that check.  However, if it isn't assigned before the check then it throws the "referenced before assignment" error.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning to movielist inside of the first if block (command == "l"), it won't be created and assigned to in any of the elif blocks, which is why your error says it's referenced before assignment. It won't exist if the command is "r", "s", and so forth.

You can fix this by adding this line:

```
    movieList = []

    while(active == True):
      #etc
```

and it will be in scope during each loop.

As a general principle, when you're writing this kind of loop-based interactive menu, you should initialize everything you need before you enter the loop for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Set movieList outside the main block.  Also, something needs to switch active to False to break the loop.

```
movieList = None
active = True
while(active):

    print("\n*** Movie Title Explorer ***\n \tl - load file of movie titles\n \tr - random movie\n \ts - search\n \t"
          + "sw - starts with\n \tk - keep - save the last displayed movie title to your favourites\n \t"
          + "f - favourites display\n \tc - clear favourites\n \tq - quit") 

    command = input("Enter a command: ")


    if(command == "l"):
        movieList = loadMovie()

    elif(command == "r"):
        if movieList:
            randomMovie(movieList)

    elif(command == "s"):
        if movieList:
            searchMovies(movieList)

    elif(command == "sw"):
        if movieList:
           startsWithSearch(movieList)
```